# Pipe to Docker stdin with arguments picked up by Python argparse

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, argparse

I would like to pipe a file using the cat command into a Docker container along with arguments related to running the Python file. The command to run this Python file is going to be mentioned in the Dockerfile as 
`RUN ["python", "myfile.py"].`

After building the Docker image using `Docker build -t test .`, I shall call the command `cat file.txt | docker run -i test --param1 value`.

I understand how arguments are accepted in the Python file using the argparse module and here is what I have:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("param1")
args = parser.parse_args()
value = args.param1
```

My question is: how do I configure the Dockerfile to route the parameter passed from the command line (param1) into the Python file's argument parser?

My findings about doing this have just shown me how to write the `cat .. | docker run ...` command.

Comment: What does the current `docker run -i test --param1 value` not do?

Comment: What I am confused about is what to write the `RUN` statement as:
What I would write if there were no arguments being passed is: `RUN ["python", "myfile.py"]`. But since there are arguments which are being passed from the command line, what is the `RUN` statement in the Dockerfile supposed to bewritten as? If I was running the python file from the command line I would write: `python myfile.py --param1 value`. Is that the place where the changes are made?

Comment: The Dockerfile RUN is used while build the image.  The `docker run` is used to run in a container from the image.  They are not really related.  Do you want to affect the image, or run something using the image?

Comment: I see. 
I might have missed this important fact: running the docker container using the docker run command is supposed to also run the Python file.
What I understand about writing the Dockerfile's `RUN` command is that the shell command is the first parameter in the list and the next parameters are the parameters to that shell command. So in my case where I do not know the parameters that are passed to my python file before hand, how do I write the `RUN` command? How do I specify the "param1" in the `RUN` command in the Dockerfile?